# sqlldr populate two tables referencing each other using foreign key

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to populate two tables referencing each other using foreign key.
to create fist table I use such configs:

***file.ctr:***

```
load data
infile 'name.csv' "str '\n'"
append into table TABLE_NAME
fields terminated by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( A, B, C, ID "TABLE_NAME_SEQ.NEXTVAL")

append into table SECOND_TABLE_NAME
           (
             TABLE_NAME_ID, --Somehow refer to generated TABLE_NAME.ID
             ID "SECOND_TABLE_NAME_SEQ.NEXTVAL"
           )
```

And I need somehow to refer to generated ID of TABLE_NAME table.

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: you can create variable outside to store value and pass it to slqldr to have consistency